# Get the jar from exe4j executable

Tags: decompilation, java, executable, jar

I've read [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3532/46118) question and it is not a duplicate to mine. I have a `.exe` file which has different contents inside when opened with 7zip. However let's say I know that it uses [EXE4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files), how can I decompile it and get the jar out of it?

Answer (score 0):

EXE4J creates a temporary folder to store the JAR. So using [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) I was able to locate the JAR file.

---

Here's how I found the answer

So as I was searching I found [this useful GitHub page](https://github.com/struppigel/Exe4jConfigExtractor/tree/main) (It should help you find the main class), and as I scrolled down in the **Embedded JARs** I found

> This script does not extract embedded JARs, it only finds their offsets. Use 7zip on the file to unpack embedded `.jar` files. Alternatively, execute the file and grab the JAR from the TEMP folder. It is named e4j_xxxx.tmp